# Save Laravel 5.4 Markdown Templates to, and retrieve from, database

Tags: php, database, markdown, laravel-5.4, email-templates

I'm developing an app that needs to have the ability for users to **create custom email templates and also send them** built into it.

I like the look of the **Laravel 5.4 markdown templates**, I could take care of the syntax generation in the front end, and then would ideally like to be able to **save them to a database table so that they can be easily maintained by users in the future rather than developers**.

So far I have built functionality to save a string containing a markdown template, retrieve it, and pass that string into an emails **build()** function.

However, I cannot for the life of me find a resource online that can advise how to render that template string correctly in a blade.

Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been coding for less than a year and using Laravel for less than 6 months so apologies if my question is a little amateur or nondescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this to render Markdown

https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark

So you can do `{!! (new \League\CommonMark\CommonMarkConverter())->convertToHtml($source) !!}` where `$source` is your database data.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Nerea, it certainly looks like it could be an option!

Comment: how would I go about processing variables in the markdown? Eg how could I make `Hello {{ $name}}` render as `Hello Bob`